# How to get new table name inside trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I tried two ways to get table name inside Trigger function. But both of them not working. My **Postgresql version is 9.5.14**

1)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_ddl2()
  RETURNS event_trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  audit_query TEXT;
  r RECORD;
BEGIN
  IF tg_tag = 'CREATE TABLE'
  THEN
    r := pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands();
    INSERT INTO ddl_history(object_name) VALUES(r.object_identity);
  END IF;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER log_ddl_info2 ON ddl_command_end EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_ddl2();



CREATE TABLE mytable(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
    first_name text,
    age integer,
    created_at timestamp(0) without time zone default now()
 );
```

Above way is giving an error:

```
pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() returning set of rows
```

2. Second way is using **TG_TABLE_NAME::regclass::text**. This also not working. It is giving TG_TABLE_NAME does not exists.
   Is there another possible way to get table name once it is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * INTO r
FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
WHERE object_type = 'table';
```

I am not sure if `object_type` is in lower case.

Comment: It returned ```public.mytable_id_seq```.

Comment: I have amended the answer.

Comment: Yes now it is working fine. Thank you very much!